# Where would this question about negotiating hourly rate go?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm not sure where to post this question.

> I'm in the process of negotiating with my current employer about my 1099 hourly rate. The background is that I was contracted to my current employer through a contracting/staffing agency do software programming, the contract was originally for 6 months, it has since ended. While under the contract,I was getting paid 35 dollar an hour as a w2 hourly. I was eligible for health insurance, dental insurance, vision insurance, 401k plan after 500 hours of working, short term disability insurance, long term disability insurance, workers compensation, life insurance etc. I don't get paid for any holidays, personal vacation days or sick days. I only get paid for the hours I work. and the maximum hour is 40 hours per week, no over time pay.
>
> And now my employer decided that they want to convert me to a 1099 employee, and is now offering me the same rate at 35 dollars an hour. I realize that this is an offer lower than the 35 dollar w2-hourly since I will be losing all the benefits and will be paying more taxes, I am trying negotiate an offer that is equivalent to w2 hourly(when I had the mentioned benefits)
>
> According to my situation, what is a reasonable rate that I can bargain for?

Comment: Why is there a tag for [`site-recommendation`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) if do what the tag says to do it then closed as off-topic?

Comment: You probably could ask it on Workplace, but asking for reasonable rate is probably too opinion-based.

Comment: Your question originally read like "I don't know where this goes so I'm asking it here". I've tweaked it a bit to make it clear that you're trying to find the right place for it.

Comment: The "what is a reasonable rate that I can bargain for?" is completely dependent on local job factors including completion, cost of living, previous benefits, vacation time, and possibly many more items. Hence, it is something that you will need to sit down and do the math and budgeting. There are too many unknowns for it to make a good question in this form on any SE site as it is very much something that you should sit down with a financial advisor and walk through - that sort of discussion you need to have isn't something that the Q&A format works well with.

Answer (score 11):

A question about how to negotiate a salary change, or how to account for differences in total compensation between W2 and 1099 employment, would be on-topic on The Workplace.  (We might already have the latter; try searching.)

A question about how much you should ask for is not on-topic there, and probably isn't on-topic anywhere on the network.  (Also, beware of "primarily opinion-based".)

The Workplace can give you the *tools* to make decisions, but we can't make decisions for you.

Other sites to consider (read the "what can I ask here" pages in the help center on all sites you're considering): PersonalFinance.SE, Freelancing.SE.

Comment: This is probably the best suggestion. I would couch the question differently, though: *"My employer wants to change from salary + benefits to hourly contract.  What do I have to account for in those benefits to make sure I'm not taking a pay decrease?"* Then you'd get a list of benefits, and you'd have to go through each one, add them up, and figure the actual figures out for your situation. You *might* be able to get a rough estimate by asking, *"What's a good starting point for estimating the cost of the benefits I'm receiving?"* but that becomes very complicated and subjective very quickly.

Comment: @AdamDavis agreed on your rephrasing.  There are two things someone in that situation needs to figure out: what am I now going to be paying for myself (that my employer previously covered), and how do I figure out how much that's going to cost me?  The first depends on your list of benefits, so you start by walking down that list (and I hope that's obvious), but there are also other hidden costs (e.g., in the US, differences in social-security taxes).  A question asking about hidden costs of switching to contract could be valuable.

Comment: Agreed.  It's a very complex question, because the employer will be getting discounts for benefits, so even knowing what the employer is paying for a given benefit doesn't actually answer the question.  This on top of government/regional/industry/cost of living/etc factors. It's either very broad and subjective, or too localized, and so making a good question will be difficult.

Comment: @MonicaCellio how much of that would be more appropriate to ask on PersonalFiance.SE instead which might be able to focus the question differently in a way that is appropriate on that site?

Comment: @MichaelT good question.  (I don't know a lot about that site.)  There's also Freelancing.SE.  The asker should review the help centers for all three sites and decide what to ask where.